# Prioritise Windows Authentication over Anonymous Authentication in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I've seen other answers saying how to secure virtual folders for Windows Authentication only. I would like to allow both anonymous AND Windows Authentication in IIS, but prioritise Windows Authentication over Anonymous Authentication. The reason for this is that the web app I am building needs to support anonymous access as well as privileged.

Is this possible? I.e. if Windows Authentication cannot authenticate against the domain, it will fall back to a generic identity, as opposed to the way it works out of the box by favouring anonymous access.

Developing on W7 with IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the steps in this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

And then just don't redirect to a login page. Basically you trap the authentication error and keep going.