# Mixed mode Authentication in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: forms-authentication, windows-authentication

**Brief on Application:** Application will be publicly available on the internet.

**Requirement:** Need to implement both windows and form authentication. I'm stuck in that. If the website is accessed by domain users (directly connected / thru VPN) it needs to authenticate via AD. Otherwise it should use form authentication. We maintain both AD / non AD users in database, once authenticated with AD, we will authorize it by using database.

I Googled but can't find an approach that works for me.

How can I proceed with the scenario?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible to mixup authentication method. I don't understand why you maintain AD users in databases... If your table contains AD users, why don't you just use form authentication?

Comment: Because if I'm connected thru VPN of my network it shouldn't ask for login, means automatically logged in to the application. We maintain AD users in the database, because Application can be accessed by only the users who all registered by App Admin in to the database.

Comment: You can try to write your own membership provider to accomplish what you want. Here is a link to a forum with someone asking about the same thing on asp.net webforms 3.0 : http://forums.asp.net/t/958504.aspx
I don't know if he succeed to fallback to a login form... 
If this doesn't work, I think your best option is to build 2 web sites. One with restricted access available publicly with form auth, and another with all access available only as an Intranet with windows auth.

Comment: Is there any possibilty to get the Windows user information like Domain\UserName without using the Windows authentication?.
I had a doubt that is Windows authentication will verify the credentials against the Domain where the IIS server is hosted or it can be configured to authenticate with multiple ADs? Please help

Comment: I found another post asking what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265223/prioritise-windows-authentication-over-anonymous-authentication-in-iis

You will see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx in the Microsoft Library that explain how you can achieve what you want. You have to allow anonymous access and set integrated windows authentication. The Windows username will be stored in Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]. I hope it helps.